# is this a valid class variable ? $this->$variablename

Tags: php, class, this

I am referencing to a variable like this

```
$this->variablename
```

but I have seen accessing variable like this:

```
$this->$variablename
```

for example in a google script

```
public function __get($key)
{
    $keyTypeName = $this->keyType($key);
    $keyDataType = $this->dataType($key);
    if (isset($this->$keyTypeName) && !isset($this->processed[$key])) {
      if (isset($this->modelData[$key])) {
        $val = $this->modelData[$key];
      } else if (isset($this->$keyDataType) &&
          ($this->$keyDataType == 'array' || $this->$keyDataType == 'map')) {
        $val = array();
      } else {
        $val = null;
      }
   }
}
```

in this example it is `$this->$keyTypeName`, is this an error or valid code?. In php 7 it is giving error.

Comment: `in php 7 this gives errors` Works for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c84e69c2676704f284930fcf4b2a82ef93bf0881

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). It accesses `$this->whateverKeyTypeNameIsSetTo`.

Answer (score 0):

They are variable's variable

```
$this->$keyTypeName
This is accessed as $$keyTypeName
```

while

```
$this->keyTypeName
this is accessed as $keyTypeName
```

Answer (score 0):

[See Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df4f1906ffd11fdd132edba34aecacc2b9529a1f)

What is $this->$var simple means that the php interpreter converter the $var and parse it together with the object $this.

If $var = "string";

and you say $this->$var, it simply means $this->string.

Check the example link attached.